# SKSpriteNode image texture looks stretched when added to SCNNode

Tags: sprite-kit, scenekit, skspritenode, scnnode

I added an SKScene that contains an SKSpriteNode image to an SCNNode, however the image looks stretched outside of the bounds of the SCNode(face node). How would I display the image inside the bounds of the SCNode face?

```
let faceSCNNode = scnScene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("faceSCNNodeID", recursively:true)  

let sprite = SKSpriteNode()
sprite.texture = SKTexture(image: UIImage(data: imageData)!)
sprite.size.width = self.texture!.size().width
sprite.size.height = self.texture!.size().height
sprite.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(frame));

let faceSKScene = SKScene(size: sprite.size)
faceSKScene!.addChild(sprite)

faceSCNNode?.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = faceSKScene
```

The image displays correctly in the faceSKScene. Once I add the faceSKScene to the contents of SKNode, it covers the entire SKNode but most of the image does not display. It looks like it could be stretched but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should check is that your bundle actually includes 2x and possibly 3x scale images. This load logic is setting a SKSpriteNode size but that property is in terms of points while the texture is typically in terms of pixels. If you have a 2x image, then the point size is 1/2 the pixel size. Also, check that the width and heights of your images are even since odd sized images will not play well with 1x,2x,3x scale sizes.